In which part are the sentence saying that the frame is part of the cot?

A cot is made of cloth stretched over a folding frame


I think that "over a folding frame" merely describes where the cloth is stretched and therefore that the sentence doesn't tell us whether the frame is part of the cot.
But native English speakers say that the sentence says that the frame is part of the cot.
What do I misunderstand?

Are you asking a question about the manufacture of this particular item, or about grammar? It's not clear what you're asking.

Because that's the way the canvas board is defined: canvas plus backing. The meaning seems clear to me. If you have problems understanding the sentence, you need to clarify. But if you have problems with the definition, this is probably the wrong site to discuss it.

@Jay I'm asking about the grammar of the sentence.

You've changed the sentence, so this is a guess. But you have a word defined by a clause. I'm guessing you understand this: A cot is made of cloth. You need to expand that: A cot is made of cloth stretched over a frame. Same pattern, but a phrase in place of a single word.

Are you saying that perhaps the stretching of the cloth over the frame might be construed as part of the cloth-making process? That is, "made of cloth that had been stretched over a folding frame"?  If so, the fact that the frame's a folding one would be irrelevant to the cot's design, and merely relevant to the cloth-making process, which isn't the case at all.  The mere fact that the folding frame is part of the definition is reason to consider the folding frame integral to the cot's design, and not just a fun-to-know fact about a (putative) cloth-making process.

A cot is made of a folding frame over which cloth is stretched as a surface to lie on.

The sentence uses the verbal expression "be made of". The subject of this verb is a thing that is made, and the object is the thing or things that were used to make something.
You can't tell from the grammar alone which of those things remain in the final item:

A stew is made of vegetables cut with a knife.

Nobody would thing that the knife is part of the stew!

A pair of spectacles are made of lenses held in place by wires.

The wires are part of the spectacles.
You just have to think in context.  You are not a space alien, you can use a little common sense! Get a picture in your mind of the frame and the canvas...Is the frame removed after stretching? Is the cot/rudder/whatever made of just the cloth? Or is the frame left in?  The space alien might not know, but I think you do.

Is it okay to say "A cot is made of a folding frame over which cloth is stretched" instead of "A cot is made of cloth stretched over a folding frame"?

The "over which" form is equally correct, but slightly longer.  You may use it for rhetorical effects of "focus" and "emphasis".

Restrictive and Non-restrictive clauses: A comma makes the difference..
Consider these two sentences:
1.My uncle who lives in New York visited us.
2.My uncle, who lives in New York visited us.
The difference between the two sentences is that there is a comma in the second sentence.
The clause in the first sentence "who lives in New York" is restrictive. It identifies "my uncle". Here the speaker has more than one uncle and he is speaking about the uncle who lives in New York.
In the second sentence, the same clause is non-restrictive. It only describes the noun "my uncle". Here it means that the speaker has only one uncle and he lives in New York.
Similarly in OP's sentence:

A cot is made of cloth stretched over a folding frame.

There is no comma after cloth, thus the clause "stretched over a folding frame" is restrictive . It signifies we're strictly talking about the cloth stretched across a folding frame. So the frame with the cloth is included in the description of a cot.
